# Perl Out Of Memory

Tags: windows, perl, memory

I have a script that reads two csv files and compares them to find out if an ID that appears in one also appears in the other. The error I am receiving is as follows:

> Out of memory during "large" request for 67112960 bytes, total sbrk() is 348203008 bytes

And now for the code:

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;

my $DAT     = $ARGV[0];
my $OPT     = $ARGV[1];

my $beg_doc = $ARGV[2];
my $end_doc = $ARGV[3];

my $doc_counter  = 0;
my $page_counter = 0;
my %opt_beg_docs;
my %beg_docs;

my ($fname, $dir, $suffix) = fileparse($DAT, qr/\.[^.]*/);
my $outfile = $dir . $fname . "._IMGLOG";

open(OPT, "<$OPT");
    while(<OPT>){
        my @OPT_Line = split(/,/, $_);
        $beg_docs{@OPT_Line[0]} = "Y" if(@OPT_Line[3] eq "Y");
        $opt_beg_docs{@OPT_Line[0]} = "Y";
    }
close(OPT);
open(OUT, ">$outfile");
while((my $key, my $value) = each %opt_beg_docs){

    print OUT "$key\n";
}
close(OUT);

open(DAT, "<$DAT");

    readline(DAT); #skips header line
    while(<DAT>){

        $_ =~ s/\xFE//g;

        my @DAT_Line = split(/\x14/, $_);

        #gets the prefix and the range of the beg and end docs
        (my $pre = @DAT_Line[$beg_doc]) =~ s/[0-9]//g;
        (my $beg = @DAT_Line[$beg_doc]) =~ s/\D//g;
        (my $end = @DAT_Line[$end_doc]) =~ s/\D//g;

        #print OUT "BEGDOC: $beg ENDDOC: $end\n";

        foreach($beg .. $end){
            my $doc_id = $pre . $_;

            if($opt_beg_docs{$doc_id} ne "Y"){
                if($beg_docs{$doc_id} ne "Y"){
                    print OUT "$doc_id,DOCUMENT NOT FOUND IN OPT FILE\n";
                    $doc_counter++;
                } else {
                    print OUT "$doc_id,PAGE NOT FOUND IN OPT FILE\n";
                    $page_counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
close(DAT);
close(OUT);

print "Found $page_counter missing pages and $doc_counter missing document(s)";
```

Basically I get all the ID's from the file I am checking against to see if the ID exists in. Then I loop over the and generate the ID's for the other file, because they are presented as a range. Then I take the generated ID and check for it in the hash of ID's.

**Also forgot to note I am using Windows**

Comment: You should always enable warnings (use warnings) when developing Perl code.

Comment: @tadmc will do...let me see what happens then

Comment: Use hashes instead of arrays.  But I don't see why you're running out of memory.

Comment: How many records are there in the OPT file? Can you give a snippet of the OPT file so that we can see what the records looks like? Also you have two hashes BOTH keyed over @OPT_Line[0] (which, incidentally, should be $OPT_Line[0]), which might be inefficient; you might be better off pushing that into one hash.

Comment: You should use indirect/lexical filehandles (e.g. open my $foo, ...) instead of direct filehandles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the cause of your error, but inside your loop where you're reading `DAT`, you probably want to replace this:

```
        (my $pre = @DAT_Line[$beg_doc]) =~ s/[0-9]//g;
```

with this:

```
        (my $pre = $DAT_Line[$beg_doc]) =~ s/[0-9]//g;
```

and same for the other two lines there.

Comment: Accessing array elements with @ instead of $ will generate a warning, but it should be fine otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `use warnings;`, you're not checking for errors on opening files, and you're not printing out debugging statements showing the lines that you are reading in.

Do you know what the input file looks like?  If it has no line breaks, you are reading the entire file in all at once, which will be disastrous if it is large.  Pay attention to how you are parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `OUT` file handle and then trying to print to it inside the `DAT` loop, which, I think might be outputting to random memory, since you closed the FILEHANDLE - surprised this didn't output an error.

Remove the first `close(OUT);` and see if that improves.

---

I still don't know what your question is, if it's about the error message it means you've run out of memory.  If it's about the message itself - you're trying to consume too much memory.  If it's why you're consuming too much memory, I'd first ask if you read my message above, then I'd ask how much memory your system has, then I'd follow up with seeing if it improves if you take the regex away.